# Using CSS3 pie on a dynamic knockout js application

Tags: knockout.js, css3pie

I've built a single page application using `Knockout.js,` where `html` nodes get added, moved and destroyed regularly, I've been developing it in Chrome, Firefox and IE 9, but had been planning to add IE8 and IE7 CSS3 support using `CSS3 PIE`.

Now I've got to the stage where I'm adding PIE and I seem to have hit a problem.

I've applied the behaviour to two `divs` - one is in the initial HTML source and the other is dynamically added.
The initially rendered div has a box shadow and border-radius as desired.

The dynamically added div has no CSS3 styling but does have the border applied with the same `CSS selector.`

Does `CSS3 PIE only` run at runtime? Can I trigger it to re-run?

Many Thanks..

Comment: Have you had a look at using the JS version? http://css3pie.com/documentation/pie-js/ (If you want my opinion though, don't use CSS3 PIE - it hogs the CPU, and websites don't need to look the same in every browser)

Answer (score 1):

In the end I solved this by applying the behaviour to a class - "ie-behaviour" and then adding this class to the elements after they are rendered, not sure why but this seems to trigger CSS3 PIE to apply all of the required styles.